Hadronic matrix element
Consider the deep inelastic scattering process $e^-\text{p}\longrightarrow e^- X$, where $e^-$ is and electron, $\text{p}$ is a proton and $X$ are generic hadrons. Let $k, k'$ be the incoming and outgoing electron's momentum respectively. Define $q:= k-k'$ and consider the case when $-q^2 \ll m_Z^2$ (where $m_Z$ is the $Z^0$ boson mass) so that only photon exchange needs to be considered.
We can write the scattering $T$ matrix as
\begin{equation}
iT_{e^-\text{p}\longrightarrow e^-X}= \left(-ie\right) \bar{u}(k')\gamma^\alpha u(k)\frac{i}{q^2}\left(-ie\right)\left<X|j_\alpha(0) |p\right>,
\end{equation}
where $j_\alpha = \sum_{f=u,d,s,c,b}Q_f \bar{q}_f\gamma_\alpha q_f$.
I don't understand these things:

why can we write the Feynman rules for the hadronic part as $\left<X|j_\alpha(0) |p\right>$?
why in $j_\alpha$ don't we consider the contribution of the top quark?


Did you get this from some reference? If so please include it so we know where you're coming from.

This was in my lecture notes from QFT, but I think the same equation for the matrix element of the hadronic part can be found in Schwartz, equation 32.75

To write a Feynman diagram, you need to consider a quark-photon interaction, but you don't fully know how quarks fit in a proton/hadrons. You do know the top quark is so heavy that a "soft" photon, as you expressly posit, would not affect it much, even if it were a major component.

Thanks! So we are assuming that the photon cannot couple to any other charged particle inside the hadrons? And why can we write down the scattering process like that and evaluate the current in 0?

A photon couples to any and all charged particles. Kinematics restricts the effective strength of such.
